# How to change affiliation name on ca-server HLF?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Based on Hyperledger Fabric First Network (v1.4) i changed names to peers, Orgs, CAs etc. There is no problem on the containers or to generate certificates the channel works fine.

```yaml
# ca's docker-compose.yaml
ca.NewOrg:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
  environment:
    - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
    - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-NewOrg
    - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
    - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.NewOrg.example.com-cert.pem
    - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${byfn_CA1_PRIVATE_KEY}
    - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
  ports:
    - "7054:7054"
  command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.NewOrg.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${byfn_CA1_PRIVATE_KEY} -b NewOrg:NewOrgpw -d'
  volumes:
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/NewOrg.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca_peerNewOrg
```

---

The admin is register fined. but i cannot enroll the users. I am using node sdk to enroll them.

```js
const secret = await ca.register({ affiliation: orgname.toLowerCase() +'.department1', enrollmentID: username, role: 'client' }, adminIdentity);
```

---

but if i replace `orgname.toLowerCase() +'.department1'` to `org1.department1` is enrolled

However, is needed to use the new organizations names and not org1, org2 etc.

---

Finally this is a part of

```sh
docker logs ca_peerNewOrg
```

`Affiliation: MaxEnrollments:0 Attrs:map[hf.AffiliationMgr:1 hf.GenCRL:1 hf.IntermediateCA:1 hf.Registrar.Attributes:* hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles:* hf.Registrar.Roles:* hf.Revoker:1]  }]} Affiliations:map[org1:[department1 department2] org2:[department1]] LDAP:{ Enabled:false URL:ldap://****:****@<host>:<port>/<base> UserFilter:(uid=%s) GroupFilter:(memberUid=%s) Attribute:{[uid member] [{ }] map[groups:[{ }]]} TLS:{false [] { }}  } DB:{ Type:sqlite3 Datasource:fabric-ca-server.db TLS:{false [] { }}  } CSP:0xc0004f80a0 Client:<nil> Intermediate:{ParentServer:{ URL: CAName:  } TLS:{Enabled:false CertFiles:[] Client:{KeyFile: CertFile:}} Enrollment:{ Name: Secret:**** CAName: AttrReqs:[] Profile: Label: CSR:<nil> Type:x509  }} CRL:{Expiry:24h0m0s} Idemix:{IssuerPublicKeyfile: IssuerSecretKeyfile: RevocationPublicKeyfile: RevocationPrivateKeyfile: RHPoolSize:1000 NonceExpiration:15s NonceSweepInterval:15m}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see `Affiliations:map[org1:[department1 department2] org2:[department1]]`, which is the default value set when affiliation is not set in fabric-ca.

```yaml
# hyperledger/fabric-ca/cmd/fabric-ca-server/config.go
# in 'defaultCfgTemplate' value

affiliations:
   org1:
      - department1
      - department2
   org2:
      - department1
```

In other words, looking at your current situation, it seems that you have not added affiliation separately.

```
# default fabric ca's log
2020/12/17 10:16:56 [DEBUG] DB: Add affiliation org1
2020/12/17 10:16:56 [DEBUG] Affiliation 'org1' added
2020/12/17 10:16:56 [DEBUG] DB: Add affiliation org1.department1
2020/12/17 10:16:56 [DEBUG] Affiliation 'org1.department1' added
2020/12/17 10:16:56 [DEBUG] DB: Add affiliation org1.department2
2020/12/17 10:16:56 [DEBUG] Affiliation 'org1.department2' added
2020/12/17 10:16:56 [DEBUG] Successfully loaded affiliations table
```

---

## Here are two ways to solve your problem.

### 1. Fabric-ca environment variable setting

This can be solved by setting the initial settings.

> There are two things to consider. in the case of fabric-ca affiliation, it cannot be set with the input parameters of the `fabric-ca-server` commands in docker-compose, and it is not even possible to set through docker-compose's `environment`.
> why? [FABRIC_CA_SERVER_AFFILIATIONS in environment variables](https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/topic/17550018)

so, We have one way.
Initial setup using configuration file.

#### 1-1) writing fabric-ca-server-config.yaml

> [fabric-ca-server-config.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/b89ee34ff745b76922f00049df07629baaf3fe5d/test-network/organizations/fabric-ca/org1/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml)
>
> - The link is fabric-samples v2.0, but fabric-ca has no changes and the configuration form is the same.

```yaml
# hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
...
affiliations:
   org1:
      - department1
      - department2
   neworg:
      - test_department
...
```

#### 1-2) updating docker-compose.yaml

> I used release-1.4 of [hyperledger/fabric-samples](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4) to match your version.

```yaml
# hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network/docker-compose-ca.yaml

services:
  ca0:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.4
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/<your_ca_org1_private_key>
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/<your_ca_org1_private_key> -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
     # mounting fabric-ca-server-config.yaml file, to ca_peerOrg1 container's $FABRIC_CA_HOME path
      - ./fabric-ca-server-config.yaml:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca_peerOrg1
    networks:
      - byfn
```

#### 1-3) Fabric-CA Up

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network && docker-compose -f ./docker-compose-ca.yaml up -d
```

#### 1-4) Checks configuration of Fabric-CA

results

```sh
$ docker logs ca_peerOrg1

2020/12/17 10:41:05 [DEBUG] Loading affiliations table
2020/12/17 10:41:05 [DEBUG] DB: Add affiliation org1
2020/12/17 10:41:05 [DEBUG] Affiliation 'org1' added
2020/12/17 10:41:05 [DEBUG] DB: Add affiliation org1.department1
2020/12/17 10:41:05 [DEBUG] Affiliation 'org1.department1' added
2020/12/17 10:41:05 [DEBUG] DB: Add affiliation org1.department2
2020/12/17 10:41:05 [DEBUG] Affiliation 'org1.department2' added
2020/12/17 10:41:05 [DEBUG] DB: Add affiliation neworg
2020/12/17 10:41:05 [DEBUG] Affiliation 'neworg' added
2020/12/17 10:41:05 [DEBUG] DB: Add affiliation neworg.test_department
2020/12/17 10:41:05 [DEBUG] Affiliation 'neworg.test_department' added
2020/12/17 10:41:05 [DEBUG] Successfully loaded affiliations table
```

#### 1-5) Run your code(registerUser) & success!

```js
// Register the user, enroll the user, and import the new identity into the wallet.
const secret = await ca.register({ affiliation: 'neworg.test_department', enrollmentID: 'user1', role: 'client' }, adminIdentity);
const enrollment = await ca.enroll({ enrollmentID: 'user1', enrollmentSecret: secret });
const userIdentity = X509WalletMixin.createIdentity('Org1MSP', enrollment.certificate, enrollment.key.toBytes());
await wallet.import('user1', userIdentity);
console.log('Successfully registered and enrolled admin user "user1" and imported it into the wallet');
```

```sh
$ node registerUser.js

Wallet path: /Users/myeongkil/Project/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/wallet
Successfully registered and enrolled admin user "user1" and imported it into the wallet
```

---

#### 2. Add authorized users

The `fabric-ca-client` has an `affiliation` command, which can be added.
See the commands and links below.
[dynamically-updating-affiliations](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#dynamically-updating-affiliations)